# Как тестировать контроллеры ASP WebAPi 2 с атрибутом Authorize?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, тестирование, asp.net-web-api

Пытался заставить создавать mock объекты httpcontext, но не работает. Где-то наткнулся на сообщение, что нужно создавать свой rest api client, например, через restsharp. Неужели все так плохо? Может есть способы?

Comment: Что именно вы собираетесь проверять в тестах? Сам факт, что стандартный механизм сработает при наличии аттрибута? Нет никакого смысла писать интеграционный тест на стандартный механизим - вы же не пишете тесты на то, что сработают стандартные байндеры, сработает десериализация, сработает сериалиация, клиенту уйдут те данные, что вы вернули из контроллера. Тестировать нужно поведение (которое уже покрыто тестами на код атрибута), а не состояние (что атрибут где-то стоит). :)

Answer (score 1):

Если речь идет о юнит-тестировании, то атрибут Authorize никак не мешает тестировать метод контроллера, за исключением методов, которые обращаются к текущему HttpContext (Например, узнать текущего юзера HttpContext.User).

В таком случае нужно создавать мок HttpContext и создавать контроллер, используя этот мок.

```
[TestInitialize]
public void SetupTests()
{
    // Setup Rhino Mocks
    rmContext = MockRepository.GenerateMock<HttpContextBase>();
    rmRequest = MockRepository.GenerateMock<HttpRequestBase>();
    rmContext.Stub(x => x.Request).Return(rmRequest);
    // Setup Moq
    moqContext = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
    moqRequest = new Mock<HttpRequestBase>();
    moqContext.Setup(x => x.Request).Returns(moqRequest.Object);        
}

[TestMethod]
public void RhinoMocksControllerContextTest()
{
    // Arrange
    var controller = new SubscribeController();
    var context = new ControllerContext(rmContext, new RouteData(), controller);
    controller.ControllerContext = context;
    var parameters = new SubscribeParameter();
    // Act
    var result = controller.SignUp(parameters) as ProcessResult<SubscribeParameter>;
    // Use ViewResult here for your results. This is a specific ActionResult I built.
    // Assert
    Assert.IsNotNull(result);
}
```

Побробнее можно посмотреть здесь - http://www.danylkoweb.com/Blog/how-to-successfully-mock-httpcontext-BT